# Validate form replace text textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a validation form checker - 
when my checkbox has the value of 1 - i want to replace some text in the TextArea with new Text. Does anyone know the correct code to do this?

everything else in the form checker works, except this one.

```
function validateForm(myForm){
if (getRadioSelected(myForm.myCheckBox) == 1) {
myForm.myTextArea.value.replace("Old Text","Replacement Text");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newString = myForm.myTextArea.value.replace("Old Text","Replacement Text");
myForm.myTextArea.value = newString;
```

The replace method returns a string but doesn't set your textarea value. This does.

-**edit**-

jsFiddle [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/BjvtS/)!

Comment: Anytime! Glad I could be of help